# How do I remove surrounding parentheses in a nested list in Scheme if that nested list has 1 element?

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, nested-lists, flatten

Say I have the list: `(a b ((c)) (d + e) ((e + f)) (g) () h)`

How do I get the following list (preferably with a function):`(a b c (d + e) (e + f) g h)`

In other words:

- If the nested list has only one element it is simplified to the element. That is `((c))` is simplified to just c in the above example. Also `((e + f))` becomes `(e + f)`.
- If the nested list has more than one element then it remains the same. That is `(d + e)` remains as `(d + e)` in the above example.
- If the nested list is null, it is simply removed.

Lastly
I'm not sure if the term flatten applies in this case.
I hope my question is clear. If not, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if your example is right. for instance, the list `((d+e) (g))` will get flattened to `(d+e g)`, according to your definition. My point is, `d+e` counts as a _single_ element; it'd be different if the list were `((d e) (g))` in which case the flattened list would be `((d e) g)`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, yes the example (a b c (d+e) (e+f) g h) is my desired result. So if I had the list ((d e) (g)) I would like to get ((d e) g).

Comment: Right, but my question was what happens with the list `((d+e) g)`, since the `(d+e)` part is just a one-element list. In scheme `d+e` is a _single_ symbol, if you want to interpret it as _three_ symbols, you *must* put spaces in between, like this `(d + e)`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I'm sorry, guess I didn't make it clear. (d+e) is a 3 element list. So I guess (d + e) would be more fitting. I shall edit my above description to show this. So ((d + e) g) remains as ((d + e) g).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x))))

(define (strip lst)
  (if (or (null? lst) (atom? lst) (not (null? (cdr lst))))
      lst
      (strip (car lst))))

(define (flatten lst)
  (cond ((or (null? lst) (atom? lst))
         lst)
        ((null? (strip (car lst)))
         (flatten (cdr lst)))
        (else
         (cons (flatten (strip (car lst))) (flatten (cdr lst))))))
```

When tested with your example, it gives the expected answer:

```
> (flatten '(a b ((c)) (d + e) ((e + f)) (g) () h))
> (a b c (d + e) (e + f) g h)
```

Comment: Thank you Óscar! That does exactly what I was looking for. It is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you need a recursive function that:

1. Checks if the list is empty
2. Checks if the first item is a list, if not `cons` it to the function applied to `cdr` of the list
3. Otherwise, applies the function to both `car` and `cdr` and `cons`ing the results.

Here's an untested attempt:

```
(define flatten
  (lambda lst
    (cond 
      ((null? lst) lst)
      ((atom? (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (flatten (cdr lst))))
      (else (cons (flatten (cons (car (car lst) (cdr (car ls))) 
                  (flatten (cdr lst)))))))
```

Where `atom?` is a function that tests if an element in a list not a list. Here is how `atom?` is defined in [The Little Schemer](http://junix-linux-config.googlecode.com/files/The.Little.Schemer.4th.2.pdf):

```
(define atom?
  (lambda (x)
    (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x)))))
```

I highly recommend The Little Schemer if you are having trouble organizing the logic of recursive functions.

Comment: Hi Eric, I appreciate your response. However when I call (flatten '(a b ((c)) (d+e) ((e+f)) (g) () h)) I get (a b ((c)) (d+e) ((e+f)) (g) () h) which is the same list. Am I missing something? Side note: I also had to add parentheses around lst in the lambda.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, when I said flatten I mean just for the nested lists and not the entire list. I'm actually not sure if the word flatten would apply in this scenario.

Comment: Upon a more careful reading of your question, I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Nevertheless, I've attempted to fix my `flatten` even if it isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks again Eric. I've attempted to make my question more clear. My scheme interpreter does not seem to like (car (car lst)) in your else clause and gives the following error: mcar: expects argument of type <mutable-pair>; given () when I do (flatten '(a b ((c)) (d+e) ((e+f)) (g) () h))